# Retorno JSON para PHP com Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, json

Estou tentando passar uma JSON (resultado de uma API do Google Place) com Ajax para o PHP. Acredito que o meu problema esteja no PHP na hora de manipular os dados, segue uma parte do código:

AJAX:

```
//GRAVA TODO O RETORNO NO BANCO...                
            $.ajax({

                types: 'GET',
                dataType: "json",
                url: 'http://'+VARendereco+'/WB_CADASTRO_USUARIO3/www/busca.php',
                data: "dados="+Dados_json+"&acao=salva_toda_busca_web",
                success: function(data){
                //alert(data[0].status);
                //$('#sub-pagina').html(data);
                //alert(data);
                alert("Gravou_busca2");
                }
            });
```

PHP:

```
if($_GET["acao"] == "salva_toda_busca_web"){
    //$matriz = stripslashes($_GET["dados"]);
    $matriz = json_decode($_GET["dados"], true);
    $itens = $matriz['results'];

        //foreach ( $itens as $e ){
    $SQL = "INSERT INTO tb_busca_geral (conteudo_busca, id_usuario, qt_resultados, local, lat, lon)VALUES('".$itens['name']."', 10, 5, '', '', '')";
    $num = mysqli_query($serve, $SQL);
    //echo $itens->name; 
        //} 
}
```

Ele grava o registro, mais em branco neste campo...
Se alguém tiver alguma ideia agradeço!

json (exemplo Google, neste formato):

[image: inicio]

[image: final]

Comment: Pode ser que seja um erro de digitação, você escreveu ali: $$_GET["dados"] , E o correto é: $_GET["dados"]

Comment: Obrigado Viniam, mas foi só na hora de copiar e colar aqui mesmo, já revisei, alem do mais ele grava o registro no mysql... só que em branco!

Comment: da um var_dump($_GET["dados"] ) antes de gravar no mysql para ver onde  você esta perdendo essa informação

Comment: Faça o seguinte: apague as 2 linhas finais, e dê um echo no $itens e verifica se os dados estão sendo recebidos corretamente, se tudo estiver correto, Tente assim: $SQL = 'INSERT INTO tb_busca_geral (conteudo_busca, id_usuario, qt_resultados)VALUES("'.$itens['name'].'", 10, 5)'; ,,,LEMBRANDO: se todos os campos forem varchar coloque tudo inclusive os números em aspas duplas.

Comment: Viniam, fiz o echo e devolve em branco para o AJAX...

Comment: Segue o resultado json conforme o Gabriel perguntou... Lembrando que o resultado json da requisição está ok, por que estou trabalhando com ele em outras funções:

Comment: Desculpe não consigo colar o retorno em json na pergunta kkk... Aparece toda errada a formatação

Comment: Coloquei duas imagens referente ao json que retorna da url, estou manipulando ele normalmente com javascript, o problema está no php!

Comment: dados_json é uma String JSON ou um Objeto já ?

Comment: Mando como um objeto ainda, tento converter com "json_decode" no php

Answer (score 0):

consegui resolver desta maneira:

```
$matriz = json_decode ( json_encode ($_POST['dados']), true);
```

Não entendi ao certo o motivo de ter funcionado só desta forma, codificando e decodificando novamente, se alguém souber explicar posta ai... Mas funcionou perfeitamente com um "foreach", e aproveitei para passar para POST que tem mais recursos de capacidade de transferência e é considerado mais seguro...

Muito Obrigado!!!